# float division by variable in C

Tags: c, floating-point, division

I am calculating salary by inflation
By random 1 to 5% the salary increase.
For exam, in 2020 inflation increased by 2%. And my salary is 1000.
Then answer should be 1000 * 1.02 = 1020.

So I made a simple code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {


    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    int inc_rate = (rand() % 5) + 1;
    float num = (100 + inc_rate) / 100;

    printf("%d  \n", inc_rate);
    printf("%f", 100 * (float)num);

    return 0;
}
```

But if I run it cannot count 1.02.

For example the outcomes

```
2
100.000000
```

How can I calculate division by C

Comment: `(100 + inc_rate) / 100;` This is done using integer division. The result will be chopped to 1 and only afterwards it is converted to 1.0. You need to convert earlier: `(100.0 + inc_rate) / 100;`

Comment: Nam, Curiously, why use `float num` and not `double num`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator "/" performs integer division if both operands are integers (the fractional part is discarded). This means that the expression

```
(100 + inc_rate) / 100
```

will always be one if *inc_rate* is an integer between one and five.

Try this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) 
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int inc_rate = (rand() % 5) + 1;
    float num = (100.0 + inc_rate) / 100.0;

    printf("%d\n", inc_rate);
    printf("%f\n", 100.0 * num);

    return 0;
}
```